# JWTの正しい実装について

Tags: django, reactjs, redux, jwt, next.js

### 前提

現在バックエンドには

- django rest framework
- django rest framework jwt

フロントエンドには

- next.js
- react
- redux

を用いてウェブサイトを開発しています。  JWT の正しい実装についていくつか質問があります。

また前提として

- Next.js を使用しているので JWT は localStorage ではなく cookies に保存
- JWT は [REST framework JWT Auth](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/) を使用
- ログインするとアクセストークンが cookies としてフロントエンドに送られる
- アクセストークンとリフレッシュの有効期限は以下の通り

```
'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=300),
'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),
'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'token'
```

これらを踏まえた上で質問させていただきます。

---

### 発生している問題

#### アクセストークンをリフレッシュするタイミングについて

この質問に関して根本的な理解が足りていないのかもしれませんが、記述した通りアクセストークンは 5 分で有効期限が切れてしまいます。

5 分以内なら `permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` のページには header にアクセストークンをのせてリクエストすることができるということはわかります。

そして、もし 5 分経過するとクッキーが自動的に削除されユーザーは再度ログインする必要が出てくる、ということを避けるためにリフレッシュという仕組みがあると考えているのですが、まずこの認識で間違いないですか？

間違ってない場合、アクセストークンのリフレッシュはいつ行うのが正解なのでしょうか？

クライアントからアクセストークンを header に乗せてリクエストを送信する前にフロントエンド側でアクセストークンの有効期限と現在時刻を比較し、もし期限切れが迫っていたら、一旦アクセストークンのリフレッシュを先に axios で行い、 cookies に新しくセットされたアクセストークンを用いて再び本来送信しようとしていたリクエストを送信する、これで合っていますか？

他に正しい方法があれば教えてください。

#### cookies にあるアクセストークンが消えてしまった場合について

cookies にあるアクセストークンは有効期限が切れると自動的に削除されますよね？

例えばユーザーがログインし、 10 分間コンピュータから離れたとします。再度ウェブサイトを見ようとしたときにはアクセストークンが消えているので再度ログインする必要性が出てきます。そしてアクセストークンがないのでリフレッシュすることもできませんよね？

この実装方法は根本的に間違っているのでしょうか？

理想としては、ユーザーに頻繁にログインさせないために定期的にアクセストークンをリフレッシュする仕組みを実装したいです。

Comment: この辺が参考になるのでは？ [Django REST JWT Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42547579/9014308), [Django Rest Framework JWT: How to change the token expiration time when logged in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43780955/9014308), [Difference between JWT token expiration_delta and JWT Refresh Expiration Delta django jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50258431/9014308), [JWT (JSON Web Token) automatic prolongation of expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26739167/9014308)

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただこれらのリンクはすでに拝見済みで、それでもなお質問の内容に沿う解決策を得ることができなかったので今回このように質問するに至りました。すみません

Comment: 私も検索してるだけですが、Tutorial記事とかあるようですね。[How to Use JWT Authentication with Django REST Framework](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/12/19/how-to-use-jwt-authentication-with-django-rest-framework.html#whats-the-point-of-the-refresh-token), [Secure Your React and Redux App with JWT Authentication](https://auth0.com/blog/secure-your-react-and-redux-app-with-jwt-authentication/)

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/174915

Comment: teratailとこちらに重複した質問を投稿するのはだめなんですか？

Comment: 遅くなり申し訳ありません。特に禁止されていません。ご参考にしてください。 https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/